# Emacs can't see system fonts on Debian

Tags: fonts, linux

I have small problem with fonts' availability in Emacs on Debian 10.

I have downloaded 'Fira Code' fonts and correctly installed them. They are exists on fc-list and are available in other programs like Libre Writer or Kate.

[image: fc-list output]

Despite this they aren't present in `font-family-list` variable. I also noticed the list doesn't contain any other system fonts like "Linux Libertine" and so on.

`font-family-list` printing output:

```
("DejaVu Math TeX Gyre" "DejaVu Sans Mono" "DejaVu Sans" "DejaVu Sans" "DejaVu Serif" "DejaVu 
Sans" "github-octicons" "Material Icons" "all-the-icons" "file-icons" "FontAwesome" "DejaVu 
Serif" "Weather Icons" "newspaper" "gothic" "mincho" "fangsong ti" "song ti" "fixed" "nil" 
"clearlyu alternate glyphs" "clearlyu arabic extra" "clearlyu arabic" "clearlyu devanagari"
 "clearlyu devangari extra" "clearlyu ligature" "clearlyu pua" "clearlyu" "clean" "fixed"
 "open look cursor" "open look glyph" "newspaper" "gothic" "mincho" "fangsong ti" "song ti"
 "fixed" "nil" "clearlyu alternate glyphs" "clearlyu arabic extra" "clearlyu arabic" "clearlyu
 devanagari" "clearlyu devangari extra" "clearlyu ligature" "clearlyu pua" "clearlyu" "clean" 
"fixed" "open look cursor" "open look glyph" "courier" "helvetica" "new century schoolbook" 
"symbol" "times" "lucida" "lucidabright" "lucidatypewriter" "charter" "terminal" "courier" 
"helvetica" "new century schoolbook" "symbol" "times" "lucida" "lucidabright" "lucidatypewriter"
 "charter" "terminal" "bitstream charter" "courier 10 pitch" "courier" "helvetica" "new century 
schoolbook" "symbol" "times" "lucida" "lucidabright" "lucidatypewriter" "charter" "terminal" 
"courier" "helvetica" "new century schoolbook" "symbol" "times" "lucida" "lucidabright" 
"lucidatypewriter" "charter" "terminal" "courier" "helvetica" "new century schoolbook" "symbol"
 "times" "lucida" "lucidabright" "lucidatypewriter" "charter" "terminal" "courier" "helvetica" 
"new century schoolbook" "symbol" "times" "lucida" "lucidabright" "lucidatypewriter" "charter" 
"terminal" "fixed" "DejaVu Math TeX Gyre" "DejaVu Sans Mono" "DejaVu Sans" "DejaVu Sans" "DejaVu
 Serif" "DejaVu Sans" "github-octicons" "Material Icons" "all-the-icons" "file-icons" 
"FontAwesome" "DejaVu Serif" "Weather Icons")
```

In the other hand there are icons installed via `all-the-icons` package.

I found related topics on that:

["emacs font: font installed but cannot set in emacs" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210953/emacs-font-font-installed-but-cannot-set-in-emacs)

["Emacs 24 not finding system fonts" - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/emacs-24-not-finding-system-fonts)

["emacs does not uses fonts from /usr/share/fonts" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149136/emacs-does-not-uses-fonts-from-usr-share-fonts)

of which the later seems to have some kind of solution, but I don't understand it at all and it is also outdated. It is something about the libfreetype package, that exists in my system packages list. Can someone explain me what does mean "[adding] *freetype library dependency to binary*"?

I would be very grateful for any help. If there is need for more information please point that.

Comment: Which Emacs package are you using? This may depend on which GUI library Emacs is linked against.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks for showing interest. I figured out what was wrong. It was because of guix-based installation of Emacs. I am new to GNU/Linux systems and I gave up using Guix until I will become more familiar system-based interactions between those kind of services.